# Beautiful solution for calling inherited private method

Tags: objective-c, architecture

Basically I want the best solution for the following problem:

```
    //  A.h
    @interface A : NSObject

    @end

    //  A.m
#import "A.h"

@implementation A

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self childWillOverride];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)childWillOverride {
    NSLog(@"childWillOverride - A");
}
@end
//  B.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "A.h"

@interface B : A

@end

//  B.m
#import "B.h"

@implementation B

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self childWillOverride];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)childWillOverride {
    [super childWillOverride]; // This is not possible
    NSLog(@"childWillOverride - B");
}

@end
```

I don't want to move the function name to A.h or I don't want to create a new Category or .h file for the function name. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: By the way, I believe when you `init` the `B` object you will call B's `childWillOverride` twice, which I'm doubt was your intent.

Comment: So `[[A alloc] init]` should call `childWillOverride` from `A`? And `[[B alloc] init]` should call `childWillOverride` from `B` or both?

Comment: @MartinR When B's `init` calls A's `init`, and when A's `init` subsequently calls `[self childWillOverride]`, it actually ends up calling B's implementation of `childWillOverride` (which subsequently calls A's implementation). Thus, when B's `init` called `[super init]`, it actually called `childWillOverride` already, and presumably should not do so again.

Comment: @Rob: My question was meant for the OP, as to find out what he wants to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I'd rather just create a separate .h file for those protected methods, like Apple did for `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>`.

Another approach (which I don't like), is to use a [private class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3):

Thus, your B.m would be:

```
#import "B.h"

@interface A ()
- (void) childWillOverride;
@end

@implementation B

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self childWillOverride];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)childWillOverride {
    [super childWillOverride]; // This is now possible
    NSLog(@"childWillOverride - B");
}

@end
```

I don't like using class extensions this way (it's strange to define the private implementation of A in B's .m file), so I'd personally use the separate .h approach.

Comment: I didn't know that the apple is solving the problem in that way. I dont' like the solution where I define the private A method in B too.

Comment: @flatronka - you are trying to do something you shouldn't, override a *private* method, so you are going to get your hands dirty one way or another. The solution shown by Rob has the benefit of being pretty clean, why don't you like it? The other solution is to call runtime methods to locate the actual implementation of the method and to call it directly - far more messy.

Answer (score 3):

I use a protected category for this kind of thing:

```
// A.h
@interface A : NSObject
@end

// A.m
#import "A.h"
@implementation A
- (void)subclassWillOverrideButNobodyElseWill
{
  NSLog(@"Heyyyyyy");
}
@end

// A+Protected.h
#import "A.h"
@interface A (Protected)
- (void)subclassWillOverrideButNobodyElseWill;
@end

// B.h
@interface B : A
@end

// B.m
#import "A+Protected.h"
@implmentation B
- (void)subclassWillOverrideButNobodyElseWill
{
  [super subclassWillOverrideButNobodyElseWill]
  NSLog(@"Worrrrrrld");
}
@end

// Something.m
B *b = [B new];
[b subclassWillOverrideButNobodyElseWill];

// Console results:
Heyyyyyy
Worrrrrrld
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code

```
if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(childWillOverride)]) {
    [super performSelector:@selector(childWillOverride)];
}
```

Comment: good idea, but this causes stackoverflow :)

Comment: No it doesn't as we will call the super not self.

Comment: @mohamede1945 - Sorry but flatronka is correct. While not a bad approach to explore it doesn't work. The `super` call effectively tells the runtime at what point in the inheritance hierarchy to start its search for a method, and in your example the method being searched for is `performSelector:`. Whether you start at `self` or `super` a search for `performSelector:` will find the same method, and that method will start its own search at `self`...